# C program to read a text file line by line then print out those lines to the terminal

Tags: c, file

I want to have a c program read a text file line by line then print out those lines to the terminal.

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* line; 

    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen("BBE.txt", "r");
    if (ifp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(ifp, "%s", line) == 1)
    {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }

    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}
```

The program when i try to run it does not print out anything to the terminal. This tells me that the while loop is not working but i am not to sure as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is not working, because `fscanf` does not return just `1` on success.

According to the man page of `fscanf`, the return value has the following meaning:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, these functions return the number of input items
>   successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The  value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set to indicate the error.

Additionally as already stated in another answer: You write to memory that is **NOT YOUR** memory:

```
char* line;
```

is just a the declaration of a pointer to a char. What you need is a contiguous array of char to write to.

You either can allocate this on the stack by declaring it:

```
char line[1000]; // Allocate a char array of the size of 1000.
```

or on the heap;

```
char* line = malloc(1000*sizeof(char)); // Allocate 1000 chars on the heap
```

here you have to free the memory afterwards

```
free(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `*line` without initialising it -> undefined behavior.

To fix that, you can use a char array instead:

```
char line[1000] = "";
```

Comment: You mean *without allocating any memory* instead of *without initialising it*, don't you?

Comment: @KenWhite as it stands pointer `*line` is uninitialised. And using any unitialised variable is UB. So what I mean is that it should be initialised before used, ie it has to point to some valid location - and that valid location has to be allocated first.

Comment: OK. So you're telling this poster that if they initialize it to NULL it will work? In this case, the variable would require being initialized with a memory allocation, and any use of it would require that memory be allocated first.

Comment: @KenWhite haha no, I didn't say initialising it to NULL would work. I only said it UB and to fix that s/he can (should) use a char buffer (char array) instead

Comment: (using char array would do away with allocation)

Comment: Yes, because it *allocates memory to store content*. And yes, you *did* say if they initialized it the code would work, and assigning NULL directly would be initialization. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I disgree with this part: "And yes, you did say if they initialized it the code would work" I did not say that, at least explicitly ;)

Comment: To nitpick: You said *without initializing it*, and directly assigning NULL to it would in fact *initialize it* (to NULL). That was the point of my initial comment. You'll also note that I didn't downvote your answer; I simply commented regarding a suggested change in phrasing.

Comment: @KenWhite that's totally fine. I don't disagree with your initial comment. It's correct in the context of pointer. However my statement isn't wrong either - because the usage of any unitialised variable (including pointer) is UB